# Аналог curl(php) на JS, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Могу-ли я загрузить страницу с помощью JS или jQuery? Например, что-бы загрузить страницу с помощью php, я делаю так:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
print_r(file_get_contents_curl('https://google.com'));
```

Как будет выглядеть аналог этого кода на JS? Моя цель — снизить нагрузки на сервере. Сайт работает на парсере, а посещаемость большая.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS